# How do I reuse var name = document.getElementById("name"); multible times in same document

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I do have the following problem:

I am retrieving data from a MySQL database with Javascript in a PHP document.
It works fine. The problem is when I want to reuse the var "ID" - in this case the first name in an `input type=text` field there is no response, please is there a sharp brain to help me.

Here is a code sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload=function() { attachBehaviors(); }; 
// 
function attachBehaviors() { 
 document.getElementById('person').onchange=function() { 
 loadUser(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);  
 } 
} 
function loadUser(optionvalue) { 
 if (optionvalue=='') {  
 alert('navn');  
 return;
 } 
 opts = optionvalue.split(','); 
 var navn = opts[0];

document.getElementById('navn').value=navn;

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdb ORDER BY ID DESC"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 $personName=$row['navn']; 

echo "<option value=\"$personName" </option>\n";
<div id="menu1">
<input type="text" id="navn" name="navn" placeholder="Navn" size="30" readonly/></br>
</div>
//and now it won't work.
<div id="menu2">    
<input type="text" id="navn" name="navn" placeholder="Navn2" size="30" readonly/></br>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) IDs have to be unique throughout the document in order to work properly! 2) I highly doubt this mix of JS and PHP works even partial ...

Comment: Where are your PHP-Tags? `mysql_*` is deprecated by the way, so you should use `mysqli_*`

Comment: `id` must be unique. You can give elements the same `class` and bind functions to them.

Comment: And to complete Sirko's comment. You should look at classes instead of id's. An id is to identify an unique field and with classes you could identify multiple fields (use the keyword this to see the clicked field)

Comment: Your options html is not properly formed as well. `echo "<option value=\"$personName" </option>\n";` should have a `>` after the value and some text for that option like: `echo "<option value=\"$personName\">$personName</option>\n";`

Comment: Your code sample will not work and would not be capable of working. You cannot just use php functions in javascript in nearly every situation one is processed by the server the other by the client.

Answer (score 0):

You mix PHP and Javascript. You can't do mysql query in a javascript tag.

Comment: ...I think that's a snippet?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The code sample is part of the real code and I can see i forgot some, sorry for that. Evrything is working just fine, except when I want to reuse var in an other input type=text. some ideas?